# ProgrammingError: column ir_ui_view.arch does not exist How to fix?

Tags: version, odoo

I can't start my localhost in database odoo8.

My log is:

```
    File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 122, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 860, in read_template
    arch = self.read_combined(cr, uid, view_id, fields=['arch'], context=context)['arch']
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 525, in read_combined
    while v.mode != 'primary':
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 835, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 928, in determine_value
    record._prefetch_field(self)
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3243, in _prefetch_field
    result = records.read(list(fnames), load='_classic_write')
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3183, in read
    self._read_from_database(stored, inherited)
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3312, in _read_from_database
    cr.execute(query_str, [tuple(sub_ids)] + where_params)
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 171, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/delgertsetseg/workspace/od8/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
ProgrammingError: column ir_ui_view.arch does not exist
LINE 1: ...e","ir_ui_view"."name","ir_ui_view"."create_date","ir_ui_vie...
```

How to fix this error?, I need any solution, please help.
My odoo version is odoo8.

Comment: My server is not starting. Whenever I start the server I land into this issue.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  And can we see the code which throws this error?  I would guess that you are looking for a column called `ir_ui_view.arch` and no such column exists ....

Comment: Try clearing your browser cookies and cache memory

Comment: Looks like an error on database creation. Try to create a new one and watch log carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you close the browser without log out and restarted the odoo server with another database. Try below solutions.

1. Restart the server with the same database which you were loged in before,
2. Clear the browser cookies and history, try again.
3. Try to log in an incognito window.

Hope it will help you.